# PHP tables not printing out?

Tags: php

I'm calling a specific function, either `getTaskList0`, `getTaskList1`, or `getTaskList2`, each the same as below, with the number after task referring to the `getTaskList` number (in `TaskManagerDAO`):

```
function getTaskList0(){
  $lst=array();
  $con=$this->getDBConnection();
  $result = $con->query("SELECT name, score FROM task0 ORDER BY score DESC");
  $i = 0;
  $counter=0;
  while (($row =$result->fetch_row()) && ($counter<5)) {
      $rec = new Task($row[0],$row[1]);
      $lst[$i++]=$rec;
      $counter++;
  }
  return $lst;
}
```

Task:

```
 <?php
class Task{
    public $name;
    public $score;

    function __construct($name,$score) {        
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->score = $score;
    }

}
```

The function is called in here:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!class_exists('Action')){
    include_once 'Action.php';
}
if(!class_exists('TaskManagerDAO')){
    include_once 'TaskManagerDAO.php';
}

class Action_DisplayList implements Action{
    public function execute($request){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['functCount']))
                $_SESSION['functCount']=0;
        $functCount=$_SESSION['functCount'];
        $functionName="getTaskList{$functCount}";
        echo $functionName;
        $dao = new TaskManagerDAO();
        $names = $dao->$functionName();
        $_SESSION['names'] = $names;
        $last = sizeof($names);
        $start = 0;
        $_SESSION['start'] = $start;
        $_SESSION['last'] =$last;
        header("Location: tasklist.php");
    }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to call the function by putting a variable at the end of the function name as a string and then calling the function. This works as I don't get any errors, but the list does not show up in the table, which is what this code is supposed to do:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['Add']) && ($_POST['name']!=="") &&!empty($_POST['Add'])){
      include 'Action_Add.php';
      Action_Add::execute();
   }
   $functCount=0;
   $_SESSION['functCount']=0;
   $names = $_SESSION['names'];
   $start=$_SESSION['start'];
   $last = $_SESSION['last'];
   for($count = $start; $count < $last; $count++){
      $name=$names[$count];
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".($count+1)."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$name->name."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$name->score."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   ?>
```

**EDIT:** 
I restarted my computer and everything and for the first run load of the page it worked perfectly. After that though, it stopped working though.

Comment: Start with dumping `$_SESSION` in the second file to see what is actually saved. If values aren't there try `session_write_close()` before `header()` line in the first file.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp The variables saved in the function  where the call to print it is are: 
`array(4) {
  ["functCount"]=>
  int(1)
  ["names"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["start"]=>
  int(0)
  ["last"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Comment: I restarted my computer and everything and for the first run load of the page it worked perfectly. After that though, it stopped working though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_start();` before start using `$_SESSION`. So in your case, try something like

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Add']) && ($_POST['name']!=="") &&!empty($_POST['Add'])){
//.... remaining code here
```

Note: To use cookie-based sessions, [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: I am doing this. It seems like everything is working when I initially run it when I first turn my computer on, but every time I run it after that it doesn't work right